# Android images issue to tablet devices

Tags: android, tablet, image-size

Currently i am making new Application in which i will get images from client side now they ask me to which sizes i need images for Application so it is working fine for tablets and devices too . I have told him that i need images of S4 device resolution i.e (1080 * 1920)px.Now i am confusing that is that image with above resolution((1080 * 1920 )px will display fine on 7 inch or 10 inch tablet or i have to use different images with different size for tablets .I want to use less images in Application for all devices including tablets too . 
Please help so that images will working fine tablets and devices

Answer (score 0):

You want to scale your images for each dpi folder so that they display properly with minimum pixelation, Android will scale the images down for you but it doesn't do a very good job and things like text can be unreadable. See this link for the level of scaling http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Mainly this line "So, to create an icon for different densities, you should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively). "

Comment: Thanks for comment. i have read this but as for 7 inch  google nexus tablet which has 1920 x 1200 so i need different image for tablet . i want to use single image .so apk size will not be increase or images it will look good in tablets too.

Comment: you can detect the screen size and load different images based on the screen size, you can also use different scaling methods of the image to preserve the aspect ratio and crop just the top/bottom etc.